# 2013 Honda Fury

Tags: engine, honda, motorcycle

My Honda Fury developed a problem while riding the other day. The bike has been running good with no problems up to that point. While riding this weekend the bike started having trouble at low speeds and idle. It started dropping the rear cylinder at idle and low speed. Once it gets above low speed it runs fine and doesn't appear to have any loss in power. The bike has about 1500 miles on it, a set of Cobra exhaust with a Cobra fuel module which I test per Cobras instructions and it looks fine. The plugs look normal and fuel and electrical connections are good. Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are you sure it isn't just the way it's supposed to run? With being a close v-twin, I'm sure it runs a lot like a Harley does, which has a definite vibration to it.

Comment: No it shouldn't run that way. I also own a Harley and it certainly doesn't all of a sudden start acting erratically without a good reason. The HD has the ability to shut down the rear cylinder if left idling to long to prevent overheating. This isn't the same thing.

Comment: I think you misinterpret what I'm saying. The HD has a specific way it idles because it's a V-twin on a common pin crankshaft. The two pistons do not fire at 360° of each other, but rather at 305° then at 415°, giving it a very uneven lope and what some would consider a weird vibration (well known to HD owners - why it's called the *Milwaukee Vibrator*). I'm not sure about your Honda, but seeing as how it's a V-twin on a common pin crank, it might have the same lope, mimicking the HD. That has nothing to do with the HD having rear cylinder deactivation.